# Official DiabloMiner.app

Tags: diablominer

Where can I get official DiabloMiner.app? Is it safe?

By safe I mean that it neither will try to steal my wallet nor will dig for somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

It's hosted at [github](https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner/).

Downloads are [here](https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner/archives/master).

It's open source, so you can check the code to see how safe it is.

There's an [old but still active thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1721) on the [bitcointalk forums](https://bitcointalk.org/).

It looks like the program is java code and so doesn't need compiling for OSX, and also that there's a script DiabloMiner-OSX.sh that runs it on OSX.

Comment: He's asking if a official_-ish_ compiled binary for OSX exists somewhere.

Comment: Oh I see.  You can tell from the '.app' can you?

Comment: Looks like it's java code, and so doesn't need compiling for OSX, and that there's a script DiabloMiner-OSX.sh that runs it on OSX.

Comment: good, include it in the answer maybe :)